# There is an error , TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace') using react-xml-parser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, react-native, xml-parsing

I am trying to fetch an XML file into my react component , but unable to fetch due to following error, I am stucked at it for a long long time , please help me resolving this.

Link to the XML: https://7targets.ai/blog/feed.xml

Here is my Component named BlogFeed.js .

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import XMLParser from 'react-xml-parser';
import { parse } from 'fast-xml-parser';
// import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
// import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "./sample.scss";

const BlogFeed = () => {
  const [data , setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://7targets.ai/blog/feed.xml", {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data)
        var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);    // Assume xmlText contains the example XML
        console.log(xml);
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("There is an error , ",error)
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogFeed;
```

It is throwing me an error where I am using XMLparser , saying :

```
There is an error ,  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at e.value (bundle.js:1:1)
    at e.value (bundle.js:1:1)
    at BlogFeed.js:19:1
```

Please help me to get through this.

Answer (score 0):

`setData` is asynchronous function, so `data` is still `undefined` when you pass it to xml parser. Just pass the axios response data directly to xml parser.

```
setData(response.data)
var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);
```